# Table com 2 td com select inputs exibindo retorno somente na primeira linha

Tags: php, mysql, select, input, while

Tenho 1 table com 1 lista de módulos, e tenho 2 colunas que tem umas opções que podem ser escolhidas através de select.

A questão é que os select's só carrega os dados na primeira linha do table, nas próximas sai em branco, acho que é a forma que estou utilizando meus loops que podem esta errado.

Segue abaixo o código da minha table:

```
    <?php
    echo" <div class='table-responsive'>
    <table class='table lista-clientes table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-condensed'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>SISTEMA</th>
          <th>STATUS</th>
          <th>NIVEL</th>
          <th align='center'>
              SALVAR
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>";
        while($rowModulosSistemas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultModulosSistemas)) {
          echo"
          <tr>
            <td>".$rowModulosSistemas["mod_sist_titulo"]."</td>
            <td>
              <select class='form-control' id='status' name='status'>
                <option></option>";
                while($rowStatus = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultStatus)) {
                  echo"<option value='".$rowStatus["STATUS"]."'>".$rowStatus["DESCRICAO"]."</option>";
                }
                echo"
              </select>
            </td>
            <td >
              <select class='form-control' id='nivel' name='nivel'>
                <option></option>";
                while($rowNivelUsuarios = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultNivelUsuarios)) {
                  echo"<option value='".$rowNivelUsuarios["ID"]."'>".$rowNivelUsuarios["DESCRICAO"]."</option>";
                }
                echo"
              </select>
            </td>
            <td align='center'>
             <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-sm'>
              SALVAR
              <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'>
              </button>
            </td>  
          </tr>";
        }
        echo"
      </tbody>
    </table> 
    ";
    ?>
```

> @Luiz MG:

```
object(mysqli_result)#5 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(6) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(14) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Lógica encontrada:

```
<?php
$x = 1; 
$y = 1; 
$z = 1; 
echo "<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>SISTEMA</th>
        <th>STATUS</th>
        <th>NIVEL</th>
    </tr>
</thead>";
while($x <= 5) {
    echo"
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                SISTEMA".$x."
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>";
                    while($y <= 5) {
                        echo"<option>".$y."</option>";
                        $y++;
                    }
                    echo"</select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select>";
                        while($z <= 5) {
                            echo"<option>".$z."</option>";
                            $z++;
                        }

                        echo"</select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>";  
            $y = 1;
            $z = 1;
            $x++;
        } 
        echo"</table> ";
```

Essa lógica encontrada é exatamente o que preciso, como poderia implementa-la no código anterior?

Comment: Boa noite! Não sou expert em php, mas analisando, vc está dando 2 loops dentro de um loop, certo? Pela lógica, os 2 loops internos só puxarão dados 1 única vez. Parte daí o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não testei aqui, mas acredito que algo assim funcione

Sempre que tiver dúvida de como está chegando o array de um var_dump($sua_var);
Como você está usando foreach, deve ser tipo assim

```
$rowModulosSistemas[0] = ...;
$rowModulosSistemas[1] = ...;
```

então sugiro usar um for em vez de while e fazer um count antes para saber
quantos resultados existem

```
$conta_repeticoes = count($resultModulosSistemas);

$rowModulosSistemas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultModulosSistemas);
$rowStatus = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultStatus);
$rowNivelUsuarios = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultNivelUsuarios);

for($x=0; $x < $conta_repeticoes; $x++) {
    echo"
      <tr>
        <td>".$rowModulosSistemas["mod_sist_titulo"][$x]."</td>
        <td>
          <select class='form-control' id='status' name='status'>
            <option></option>";

              echo"<option value='".$rowStatus["STATUS"][$x]."'>".$rowStatus["DESCRICAO"][$x]."</option>";

            echo"
          </select>
        </td>
        <td >
          <select class='form-control' id='nivel' name='nivel'>
            <option></option>";
            while() {
              echo"<option  value='".$rowNivelUsuarios["ID"][$x]."'>".$rowNivelUsuarios["DESCRICAO"][$x]."
                </option>";
            }
            echo"
          </select>
        </td>
```

Outra dica, que agrada algumas pessoas, como eu, acho que fica mais fácil pra
você ler o código, sem usar o "echo" toda hora pra imprimir o HTML.
Faça o teste, exemplo:

em vez de:

```
if($x){
    echo "<div class='qualquer'>A variável $x é verdadeira!</div>";
}
```

experimente:

```
 <?php 
    if($x){
 ?>
        <div class='qualquer'>A variável <?= $x ?> é verdadeira!</div>     
<?php 
    }
?>
```

Sei que parece pior de início, mas em vários casos que utiliza muitas tags html
com aspas simples ou duplas, facilita bastante, você não fica quebrando a cabeça pra concatenar tudo. Outra grande vantagem é que quando você fizer um echo grande como os do seu código, fica mais fácil de você entender a indentação do código, caso use uma IDE ou bom editor de textos.

Abraço!

Comment: Otácio, acho que vi meu erro, em vez de $rowModulosSistemas["mod_sist_titulo"][$x], o certo é $rowModulosSistemas[$x]["mod_sist_titulo"], em todos os casos o $x vem antes. Testa aí e fala pra gente, vlw!

Comment: Da um var_dump($rowModulosSistemas); antes do for e cola o código aqui pra eu ver por favor. Normalmente começa a partir do 0, mas pode ser que esteje começando do 1 no seu caso, aí teria de ser for($x=1...), mas passa o var_dump() que é melhor pra confirmar.